# first search algorithm

Tags: java

I need to use the first search algorithm

Can anyone assist me in regards how I use first search algorithm?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Prolog for a list, the words closed and open have a common terminology. Your open list are not open. An open list ends with a variable and not `[]`, thus the name `open`. I.e. `[A]` should be `[a|Hole]`. Also all of your list are using variables and not terms. Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the states by alphabetical order from Node A the below is the Open/Closed list maintained for Depth First Search traveral for the above graph. Answer:

[image]

Comment: Hey @J013R, Appreciate the comment, and image. I know this may be a trivial question but could you explain your route/algorithm used? Comparing mine to yours is very different and I am just try to understand how you got to the answer within the linked picture.

Comment: Since i don't see any heuristic function i am expanding the nodes alphabetically. I am starting from the node A. From node A, i can expand the nodes F and G. Because it is depth first serach, i am selecting the node F for the next expansion and go to E. From node E, i can expand C, D and G. Since G is already in the open list i am going to add just C and D. Then i pick the first node from the open list and going to expand in the same way until i reach my goal. In my algorithm, Open list contains the unvisted nodes and Closed list contains the visited nodes.

Comment: Programatically, The data structure we use for the open list determines whether we perform Breadth first search or depth first search. For depth first search the open list is a stack. The node present at the top we wil be expanded first and the child nodes will be added to the stack. In this case, A -> F,G -> E,G -> C,D,G -> D,G -> G. If we are performing Breadth First Search our open list will be a queue. In this case, A -> F,G -> G,E .... and so on

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do *open* and *closed* mean in this context of this problem?

In Prolog a ***closed** list* is a list terminated by the atom `[]`, representing the empty list.

In bracketed list notation that would be a list like this:

```
[a,b,c]
```

In formal `./2` notation, that list is represented by this Prolog structure:

```
.( a , .( b , .( c , [] ) ) )
```

Whilst the same list as an ***open** list* is this:

```
[ a , b , c | Some_Unbound_Variable ]
```

or in `./2` notation:

```
.( a , .( b , .( c , Some_Unbound_Variable ) ) )
```

I do not believe that that is what you're looking for. Please explain.

Your graph looks to be a *directed*, *cyclic* graph, which is to say that edges may be traversed only in one direction (One can travel from A to G, but not from G to A), and that it contains *cycles*, meaning that starting from one node within the graph and traversing the graph, you will eventually get back to your origin (a cycle). And that leads to endless loops, unless you track the places you've been.

You may represent your graph thus:

```
edge( a , f ).
edge( a , g ).
edge( c , a ).
edge( c , d ).
edge( d , c ).
edge( d , f ).
edge( e , c ).
edge( e , d ).
edge( e , g ).
edge( f , e ).
```

And traversing a graph is pretty trivial:

```
traverse( Origin, Destination, Path ) :-
  edge(Origin,_),
  traverse( Origin, Destination, [Origin] , Path )
  .

traverse( A, B , Vs , [B|Vs] ) :- % we can get from A to B
  edge(A,B)                       % - if A and B are directly connected.
  .                               % otherwise...
traverse( A, B , Vs , P      ) :- % we can get from A to B
  edge(A,X) ,                     % - if we can get from A to some X
  X \== B   ,                     % - such that X is not B
  \+memberchk(X,Vs) ,             % - and that we have not yet visited X
  traverse(X,B,[X|Vs],P)          % - and see if we can get from X to B
  .                               %
```

Upon success, `Path` should be unified with the path taken through the graph in reverse order, so using your graph as an example, `Path = [G,E,F,A]` says that you traveled `G <- E <- F <- A`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the answer given by @J013R, you can use the following program:

```
dfs_traversal(Root) :-
   format('Open    Closed        Visited\n'),
   dfs_traversal([Root], [], -).

dfs_traversal(Open, Closed, Visited) :-
   format('~|~w~t~7+ ~|~w~t~13+ ~w\n', [Open, Closed, Visited]),
   (   Open = [Node|Rest]
   ->  findall(Successor, successor(Node, Open, Closed, Successor), Successors),
       append(Successors, Rest, NewOpen),
       dfs_traversal(NewOpen, [Node|Closed], Node)
   ;   true ).

successor(Node, Open, Closed, Successor) :-
   arc(Node, Successor),
   not(member(Successor, Open)),
   not(member(Successor, Closed)).

arc(a, f).
arc(a, g).
arc(c, a).
arc(c, d).
arc(d, c).
arc(d, f).
arc(e, c).
arc(e, d).
arc(e, g).
arc(f, e).
```

Example:

```
?- dfs_traversal(a)
Open    Closed        Visited
[a]     []            -
[f,g]   [a]           a
[e,g]   [f,a]         f
[c,d,g] [e,f,a]       e
[d,g]   [c,e,f,a]     c
[g]     [d,c,e,f,a]   d
[]      [g,d,c,e,f,a] g
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Should [d,g] when c visited not be [d,a] as c doesn't lead to g.